# Half of mesh looks darker when I attempt to add normal map

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, normal-map

[image]

Alright, so I made a model in blender, and I notice something weird when I create a new image and attach it in the node editor.  My intention is to use a high-poly model I sculpted to bake a normal map onto the low poly mesh.  However, even before I bake the normal, Something weird happens:  One half of the model appears to be darker than the other half.

[image]

The boundary between the light and dark areas of the mesh is exactly where I marked the seams for the UV.  This doesn't disappear when I look at it in either the materials or rendered views, nor does it disappear when I bake the map. After I bake the map, it doesn't disappear when I create a new image and connect it to the normal map either.  I searched around, and the most common fix for problems like this is to look at which directions the normals are facing.  Unfortunately, I've taken a look, and it appears that the normals are already facing the right direction.

Update:  I have solved this problem on the tongue by setting the normal map vector to "UV Map", but this doesn't work on the body mesh.

Extra update:  It doesn't work on any of the other meshes, even ones that have only one material attached to them.  I have no idea why the tongue normal works when nothing else does.

Comment: hello, maybe share your object so that we can try (both the high and low poly)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still suffers from this problem: change the *Color Space* to *Non-Color* on the *Image Texture* node of your normal map.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Texture you created was not a 'clean slate' for a normal map. I must be created with an RGB value of 0.5,0.5,1 and must be set to Non-Color before baking.

The secondary issue with the broken normals sticking around is most likely that you're baking *with* that broken normal map. Blender's normal baker will calculate the Shader normals, not surface normals !
You would have gotten a 'circular dependence' warning.

The tongue normal works most likely because of a coincidence in your normal map and the exact orientation of the tongue's UV island

(revival because the only other answer doesn't address the issue at all and recommends a fix that is verifiably already done)